# iostream linker error

Tags: c++, c, linker, iostream

I have some old C code that I would like to combine with some C++ code.

The C code used to have has the following includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mysql.h"
```

Now I'm trying to make it use C++ with iostream like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql.h"
```

But I keep getting the following linker errors when I compile:

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::string::size() const'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::string::operator[](unsigned int) const'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::string::operator[](unsigned int) const'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::string::operator[](unsigned int) const'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>
> [Linker error] undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
>
> ld returned 1 exit status

How do I resolve this?

Edit: My compiler is Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The C `string.h` header and the C++ `string` header are not interchangeable.

Overall, though, your problem is that the file is getting properly compiled, but the wrong runtime library is getting linked in.

Dev-C++ uses GCC.  GCC can correctly determine the language in a file based on file extension, but won't link the right runtime library in unless you specifically ask it to (`-lstdc++` at the command line).  Calling GCC as "`g++`" (or, in your case, "`mingwin32-g++`") will also get the right language and will link the needed library.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link against your C++ runtime.  It depends on your platform and compiler, but adding `-lc` to your linker command might do it.

So might linking using your C++ compiler rather than `ld`.

In any case, you probably have to link using the C++ compiler rather than `ld` if you want your C++ code to work correctly -- it's often required for exceptions and static initializers to work correctly...

Comment: Won't `-lc` link with `libc` which is a C runtime library, not C++? For C++, one needs to link with C++ Standard Library, `libstdc++`, using `-lstdc++` parameter to `gcc` (or just using `g++` which does it automatically). Don't try to help if you don't know how, because you may equally well do a mischief.

Comment: I specified -lC, which is the C++ runtime on some unixes, not -lc.

My 2nd paragraph also stated that the OP could link using the C++ compiler, which would provide the correct libraries and settings for the platform.

Comment: I was not able to use -lC. Google interpreted my search without caps but the question I found about libc had a response that said to check for libc.a. That was there, no libC anything, and no libC even mentioned in the repo apart from libconfuse... but there was libc++.a and the packages libc++1-13, etc. So I tried `-lc++` and it worked. Where did you guys find `-lC`? Am I using the wrong library?  Is this strictly a dev-cpp thing?

Comment: I am having issues w/ Clang and found the switch `-std=<value>`. You can just add the switch `-std=` and give it a run and it should list the available options.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same exact error when trying to compile with Cygwin (`g++`).

Adding the `-L/usr/local/bin -L/usr/lib` to the compilation command should work.

This may be specific to Cygwin but it might help solve your problem as well.

Comment: Had this issue and this fix worked in cygwin. Thanks so much! Note - I only had to add `-L/usr/lib` as `/usr/local/bin` was empty for me. Although I'd probably still recommend using both as it won't hurt