# undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'

Tags: c, matrix, coredump

I write this code to read 3 files, TM is the size of square matrix, LER the No. of rows of an array and from last value define a non-square matrix of (ler/2)*2

Then... the code read a file with some relations, all are numbers and are assign to C[ler].

Then ... C[ler] is assigned to B[ler/2][2].

Those coordinates, per row, in B[ler/2][2] are assign to a and b.

a and b are the row and the column of the matrix A[tm][tm] where to add 1.

My code crashes and I don't see what the error is.

When I try to compile it, the compiler **gcc -g -o MatSim MatSim.cpp** prompted:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:75: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:75: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also, when I try to compile it, the compiler **f77 -o MatSim MatSim.cpp** prompted:

```
/tmp/cc6ewlkf.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
MatSim.cpp:(.text+0x17ad4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
MatSim.cpp:(.text+0x17ad4f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Solution**

The main problem was a library problem, Compile your code using:

```
 g++ -g -o MatSim MatSim.cpp -lstdc
```

Still not working?  Install libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Comment: Does the compiler give an error? Are you sure you are correct when saying "the compiler gave an exit status of 1" and not the program gave an exit status of 1?

Comment: Celeritas, yes, this is what I receive right after I execute any of the  compilers [gcc o f77]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find c++ libraries on unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867164/cant-find-c-libraries-on-unix)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler!!!!  you and Reinier have enlightment my code and now I can really go forward!!!!

Comment: I had a similar issue using clang, it turns out adding the `-lstdc++` switch works for this as well.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You can resolve this in several ways:

- Use `g++` in stead of `gcc`: `g++ -g -o MatSim MatSim.cpp`
- Add `-lstdc++`: `gcc -g -o MatSim MatSim.cpp -lstdc++`
- Replace `<string.h>` by `<string>`

This is a linker problem, not a compiler issue. The same problem is covered in the question [iostream linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/264057/1380680) – it explains what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Reiner... I tried your suggestion and I get:

_g++ -g -o MatSim MatSim.cpp -lstdc

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status_

Comment: If you go with the extra library option, then you should use `-lstdc++`, not `-lstdc`. But if you use g++, then it is not necessary to add that library.

Comment: Thanks Reinier!!!!  you and Jonathan Leffler have enlightment my code and now I can really go forward!!!!

Comment: I think this is an human error: it is not right to compile c++ code with gcc (instead of g++) (as I was doing wrong myself and googled here :)

Comment: I tried to ndk-build to jni directory. I think your answer for one .cpp not for the directory. Do you have solution?

Answer (score 7):

Most of these linker errors occur because of missing libraries.

I added the **libstdc++.6.dylib** in my Project->Targets->Build Phases-> Link Binary With Libraries.

That solved it for me on Xcode 6.3.2 for iOS 8.3

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, man. You just solved my problem. I was trying to compiling a target for unity test in my project using gtest-1.7.0 Framework and Xcode Version 6.3.2.

Answer (score 2):

g++ is equivalent to
gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc

I was getting a similar error while using sizeof() method. By using g++ or above tags with gcc, the code got compiled.