# Ignoring return value of fscanf and Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

I was wondering how to solve a `Core dumped issue` on my C code.

When I compile it with: `g++ -g MatSim.cpp -o MatSim -lstdc++ -O3`, I get three warnings, this is one (The other two are similar and are only differentiated by the string variable name):

```
MatSim.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MatSim.cpp:200037:27: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
 fscanf(TM,"%255s",string2);
```

The principal aspects of my code and the related part that the compiler reports:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int to_int(char string[256])
{
    if( strcmp(string,"0") == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }

...

    else if( strcmp(string,"50000") == 0 )
    {
        return 50000;
    }
    return -1;
}   

int main()
{
int a,b,div,value,k,i,j,tm,ler; 
    char string[256];
    char string1[256];
    char string2[256];

FILE *TM;
TM = fopen("TM","r");
if( (TM = fopen("TM","r")) == NULL)
{  
    printf("Can't open %s\n","TM");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(TM,"%255s",string2);
tm = to_int(string2);
fclose(TM);

...

}
```

I have tried the reported suggestion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906275/undefined-reference-to-stdios-baseinitinit) and I tried to understand what was posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault). But, I don't see its application on my code.

Finally, when I run the exe file, it returns:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: `TM = fopen("TM","r"); if( (TM = fopen("TM","r"))`  Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: My tough was: First, open the file and then check if the file is ok

Comment: `MatSim.cpp:200037:27` - wow.  *thank you* for not posting the other 200000 lines of code.

Comment: @beginner But that is not what that code you have does.

Comment: @beginner Also, if you're using C++, you should be aware of things such as `streams` and usage of `std::string`.  So pick a language -- is it C or C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I bet you are completely right what your are suggesting me. But, I don't have the proper answer because I'm a beginner. I would be thankful if you recommend me some literature to know what you are asking me. Thank you so much in advance : )

Comment: His point is you are using C language calls and structures not C++, yet the question is tagged with C++. Likely he wants to update the tagging to more reliably represent the question. As for how to use strings and streams in C++, the list of literature is quite deep. I'd start with a web search for C++ IO stream tutorial . If you get through that without also coverng strings, I'll be amazed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're `fopen()`ing the file twice. Just get rid of the

```
 TM = fopen("TM","r");
```

before the `if` statement.

That said, you should check the value of `fscanf()` to ensure success. Otherwise, you'll end up reading an uninitialized array `string2`, which is not null-terminated which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Please be aware, almost all `string` related functions expect a null-terminated char array. If your array is not null terminated, there will be UB. Also, it is a good practice to initialize your automatic local variables to avoid possible UB in later part of code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried both suggestions and none worked : (

Comment: Thank you and the only addition to omit the warning was to eliminate -O3. The rest you are right (+1) and check for answering first. Have a good day : ).

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file twice.

Alll you need is this:

```
FILE *TM = fopen("TM","r");
if (TM == NULL)  { /* file was not opened */ }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried both suggestions and none worked : (

Comment: No, the code works.  If the file `TM` cannot be opened for reading, then `TM` is NULL.  A check is made to see what `TM` was set to.  So those two lines do indeed work.  Your attempt absolutely did not work for the reasons stated.  If you have a further issue, then it is the other parts of your code (I bet the string handling stuff) that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right the only addition to omit the warning was  to eliminate -O3. The rest you are right (+1).  Have a good day : )