# How to create a shared c library from a static c and c++ library?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

## Summarize

**I'm integrating a static library based on c/c++ into a shared library based on c (using cmake on linux).**

I have errors like this: `` libmylib.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' ``

The problem is strongly related with the use of c++ and its linking to the shared library. If I avoid the shared library (even another static library) no error occurs. Because of my project **I can not avoid** that shared library which uses the static library.

**How to generate a properly shared library from an c/c++ static library and new c source code?**

PD: I'm sorry for the long question, I'm posting the code in order to give you some context of my problem.

## C++ code

cppexample.hpp

```cpp
typedef struct cpp_api
{
    int (*func_ptr)(const char *, int);
} cpp_api;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

const cpp_api* getApi();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

cppexample.cpp

```cpp
int apiFunc(const char *strc, int value)
{
  std::string str(strc);
  std::cout << "Api call: " << str << std::endl;
  return value;
}

static const cpp_api libapi =
{
    &apiFunc,
};

extern "C"
{
  const cpp_api* getApi()
  {
    return &libapi;
  }
}
```

## C code

example.h

```
void doSomething();
```

example.c

```
#include "example.h"
#include "cpp_lib/cppexample.hpp"

void doSomething()
{
  const cpp_api *api = getApi();
  int result = api->func_ptr("hello!", 12);
}
```

mainApi.h

```
void callDoSomething();
```

mainApi.c

```
#include "mainApi.h"
#include "mix_lib/example.h"

void callDoSomething()
{
  doSomething();
}
```

main.c

```
#include "mainApi.h"
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  callDoSomething();
  return 0;
}
```

## Cmake code

Libary gene

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release") #Not debug
set(THIS MAINLIB) #project name
project(${THIS} C CXX) #For c and c++
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) #c99
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) #c++11
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) #fPIC

set(MAIN_LIB_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

###### MAIN LIB ######
include_directories(${MAIN_LIB_ROOT} ${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main) 
list(APPEND MAIN_LIB_SOURCES
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main/mainApi.h"
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main/mainApi.c")
set(MAIN_LIB_NAME mainlib)
add_library(${MAIN_LIB_NAME} STATIC ${MAIN_LIB_SOURCES})
include("${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/cpp_lib/cpp_lib.cmake")
include("${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/mix_lib/mix_lib.cmake")
setup_cpp_lib()
setup_mix_lib()

###### MAIN EXECUTABLE ######
add_executable(${THIS} "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main.c")
target_link_libraries(${THIS} PUBLIC ${MAIN_LIB_NAME})
list(APPEND MAIN_INSTALL_BINS 
            ${THIS})
```

setup_cpp_lib()

```
list(APPEND CPP_LIB_SOURCES
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/cpp_lib/cppexample.hpp"
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/cpp_lib/cppexample.cpp")

function(setup_cpp_lib)
  add_library(cpplib OBJECT ${CPP_LIB_SOURCES})
  target_sources(${MAIN_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:cpplib>)
endfunction()
```

setup_mix_lib()

```
list(APPEND MIX_LIB_SOURCES
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/mix_lib/example.h"
            "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/mix_lib/example.c")

function(setup_mix_lib)
  add_library(mixlib OBJECT ${MIX_LIB_SOURCES})
  target_sources(${MAIN_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:mixlib>)
endfunction()
```

Until here the `libmainlib.a` is created. I copied that library and the `mainApi.h` and `main.c` to another project and the error occurs

## Cmake with the error

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release") #Not debug
set(THIS MYPROJECT) #project name
project(${THIS} C CXX) #For c only
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) #c99
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) #c++11
set(MAIN_LIB_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}") #current cmakelists path

include_directories(${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/includes) #includes for library headers
add_library(mylib SHARED "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main.c")
add_library(mainlib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mainlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/lib/libmainlib.a)
target_link_libraries(mylib mainlib)
add_executable(${THIS} "${MAIN_LIB_ROOT}/main.c")
target_link_libraries(${THIS} mylib)

list(APPEND MAIN_INSTALL_BINS ${THIS})
install(TARGETS ${MAIN_INSTALL_BINS} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
```

## Errors

```
libmylib.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
libmylib.so: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
libmylib.so: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
libmylib.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [MYPROJECT] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MYPROJECT.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

===Edit===

> I have a static library called `libmainlib.a` (simulates a complex
>   library that was modified injecting c++ code). That library is used to
>   generate a shared library called `libmylib.so` (simulates another
>   complex library that I didn't modify but uses the static library).

Comment: This line 
target_link_libraries(${THIS} mylib)

Were you trying to link to mainlib?

Comment: @user3389943 is the target_link_libraries(mylib mainlib) I'm trying to link mainlib to mylib in order to use mylib in another projects.

Comment: is it possible to ask for a recompiled version of the static library?   i was in similar situation  that i need to make out .so files out of a binary distributed static library  .   after days of research and trying , the library was only proofed to missing critical compile option for my goal.   i end up to go through a longer process to gain read access of the library source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got that undefined references because `mylib` library is **linked as C** object. But since the static library `libmainlib.a` is a C++ one, it requires C++ linking. For more info about origin of such undefined references that question: [undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906275/undefined-reference-to-stdios-baseinitinit).

Such incorrect linking is because the library `mainlib` in your second code is `STATIC` `IMPORTED` (both keywords are important) and CMake isn't aware of the actual language of that library.

You need to hint CMake that given library is actually a C++ one and requires C++ linking:

```
set_property(TARGET mainlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES CXX)
```

Your first code works correctly, because its `mainlib` library, while it is STATIC, is not `IMPORTED` one and CMake knows its sources. As a source `cppexample.cpp` is definitely a C++ one, CMake treats `mainlib` library as C++.

Comment: Thank you very much! that helps me to found that I also need to add "Libs.private: -lstdc++" inside of the "libmainlib.pc" file

Comment: If you have `.pc` file for your library, you may also use [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPkgConfig.html#command:pkg_check_modules) for work with this library in CMake. Since CMake 3.6 this command may produce IMPORTED target, so you need only to pass that target to `target_link_libraries` and everything will work.