Octave build doesn't link LAPACK properly
I am trying to install Octave 9.2.0 in a specific directory since I'm not root, including BLAS, LAPACK and FFT3W. I work on RedHat 7.
The BLAS and LAPACK libraries are available under openblas which I have.(It's a system library and is found by ./configure command).
I've manually installed the FFT3W libraries under a specific directory, so these are available too. They are found by ./configure command)
The command to configure Octave is the following:
./configure --prefix=/path_to/octave-9.2.0 --with-qt=5 --with-blas=/path_to/openblas-0.2.20/lib/libopenblas.so --with-lapack=/path_to/openblas-0.2.20/lib/libopenblas.so --with-fftw3-includedir=/path_to/fftw-3.3.10/include --with-fftw3-libdir=/path_to/fftw-3.3.10/lib --with-fltk=/path_to/fltk-1.3.8 --with-fftw3f-includedir=/path_to/fftw-3.3.10/include --with-fftw3f-libdir=/path_to/fftw-3.3.10/lib --with-z-includedir=/path_to/zlib-1.2.11/include --with-z-libdir=/path_to/zlib-1.2.11/lib --without-curl --disable-docs

If I don't specify the zlib library I will get an error about the function "uncompress2" during the make process.
Below the errors after typing make
/bin/ld: liboctave/.libs/liboctave.so: undefined reference to `zgetri_' 

..other libraries...

/bin/ld: libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base_library_init()'

/bin/ld: libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `uncompress2@ZLIB_1.2.9'

I tried checking: ldd libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so and ldd liboctave/.libs/liboctave.so
and I don't see any lib missing.
Is there anything I'm missing here? Is there anyone was able to compile the latest Octave in a similar way I am doing here? Shoul I use a newer openblas library?

What is the compilation command that fails (or one of them, if there are many failures)? The problem with std:: symbols looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907227/4165552 , but I guess it depends what are your dev tools on that redhat machine (redhats are known to be ultra-outdated, and v7 already reached end of life).

You can do some standard debugging, take a look at this big topic, find if your sources are linked with correct libraries (e.g. if linker tells you that uncompress2@ZLIB_1.2.9 is missing, take a look if this symbol is present in nm -D libz.so used to build the project).
